# JSON file reading and data handling

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am reading a JSON file of this kind:

```
{"message":["Untitled1a","Untitled2a","Untitled3a","Untitled4a"],"name":["Untitled1b","Untitled2b","Untitled3b","Untitled4b"]}
```

every thirty seconds an automatic reload reloads all the data, by deleting everything and then allocating all objects for the above data. Is there a way to reload just the new data? for  example if everything remains the same, no new data is loaded or deleted, while if an UNtitle 5 is added, just load that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some variable or marker in JSON which represents whether this is the same JSON parsed before or is it the new one having some modified values or some new values added.

If you want to download loads of new data you could use the concept of paging.In paging you download the data in parts.